# NPE when using triggers for session based windowing

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have use case for session based windowing where session gap = 10 mins and trigger emits on every element that is added to the session window on accumulation mode.

dataflow version 2.1.0

```
sessionCollection.apply("GroupSessionsByKey", 
         Window.<KV<String, Event>>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(10)))
               .triggering(                              
                     AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1)).accumulatingFiredPanes());
```

I get the following error when I try to run pipeline locally using DirectRunner.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Outputs for non-root node GroupSessionsByKey are null
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:864)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:606)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:594)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy$Node.access$500(TransformHierarchy.java:276)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.runners.TransformHierarchy.visit(TransformHierarchy.java:210)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.traverseTopologically(Pipeline.java:440)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.validate(Pipeline.java:552)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:296)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.Pipeline.run(Pipeline.java:283)
    at com.homedepot.personalization.orangestream.pipelines.OrangeStreamPipeline.execute(OrangeStreamPipeline.java:56)
    at com.homedepot.personalization.orangestream.main.OrangeStreamMain.main(OrangeStreamMain.java:27)
```

=========================================================================

Here's the full transform which still gives me NPE

```
PCollection<KV<String, Event>> sessionCollection = inputCollection.apply("Process Incoming Events", ParDo.of(new SomeDoFn()));

// Session based windowing
PCollection<KV<String, Event>> sessionBasedPCollection = sessionCollection.apply("GroupSessionsByKey", Window.<KV<String, Event>>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(10))).triggering(AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(1).accumulatingFiredPanes());

// Group by key
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<Event>>> groupByKeyCollection = sessionBasedPCollection.apply("GroupingElementsByKey", GroupByKey.create());

// Process and extract elements and persist to bigtable
PCollection<String> elCollectionPerSession = groupByKeyCollection.apply("AccumulateElementsPerSession", ParDo.of(new AccumulateElementsPerSession()));

// Write to DB to verify
elCollectionPerSession.apply("WriteToBigTable", ParDo.of(new WriteSessionBasedWindowingElementsToBigTable("project", "instance_name", "table")));
```

Comment: Can you share more code from your pipeline? specifically, are you passing your windowed sessions down to a next transform?

Comment: I commented out all the next transforms, still see the error. If I remove triggering(AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow().withEarlyFirings(          AfterPane.elementCountAtLeast(100))).accumulatingFiredPanes()); it executes without any exceptions.

Comment: The error that is being raised seems to indicvate that the PCollection coming from your "GroupSessionsByKey" transforms is not being consumed by any other transform. Is that not what's happening?

Comment: Added all the transforms that also throw NPE.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. I think the only missing piece to file a bug here is where "inputCollection" comes from?

Comment: The inputCollection is a PCollection from PubSub subscription messages (streaming mode).
PCollection<String> inputCollection = pipeline.apply("PubSub Read", PubsubIO.readStrings().withIdAttribute(ID).fromSubscription(<subscription_name>);